# How I can select input with index or name , jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select element with name with jquery but it giving me error don't know whey.

trying select element with name

```
  $("input[name=session[username_or_email]]");
```

trying to select element with index

$("input:eq(1)");

"ncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': 'input:eq(1)' is not a valid selector.

VM451:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': 'input[name=session[username_or_email]]' is not a valid selector.
    at :1:1

Can you help with that please.

Comment: Can you post the HTML code, so that we can understand what you are trying?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting input element by name:

```
$('input[name="myInputName"]');
```

Selecting input element by index:

```
$('input:eq(1)');
```

In that case the element counter start with 0, so the first input element of the DOM have index 0. Don't forget to include the jQuery library in your code at the bottom of the body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name="myInputName"]').on('click', function() {...});
    $('input:eq(1)').on('click', function() {...});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for this `jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )`

- **attribute**: An attribute name.
- **value**: An attribute value. Can be    either a valid identifier or a
  quoted string.

Ex : `$( "input[name='man']" )`

Try this hope this helps you !